# how to display upsell product in magento 1.9, rwd theme

Tags: magento

I am trying to add upsell product on product page, i have added usell product from backend, after this upsell product is not show in frontend. i have refreshed cache and reindex from backend after all these upsell product in not display.

Comment: Please check catalog.xml and view.phtml......I guess, you are missing upsell block in catalog.xml. Also you need to call upsell block in view.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please checkout your catalog.xml  node with following code if it is in comment remove comments and also make sure that this block called in view.phtml file.

```html
   <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
                    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
                </block>
```

Let me know if you have any query